# How do I add an image file in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

I'm new to netbeans and I simply want to add a .png and a .gif file from my local computer into my project, and I cannot find an option to do this. I'm running Netbeans 7.0 on MacOSX.

When I right click on a directory and select New -> Other, I can't find an option for image files in the wizard. File -> New File goes to the same wizard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite easy: Just copy the file from source folder and paste it into the desired folder of your Netbeans project tree (inside the IDE).

Comment: Thanks... I had already tried that and was getting an error about the destination folder being the same as the source, but now it's working. *thumbs up*

Comment: I think they should consider "listening" to drag and drop !

Answer (score -1):

Yes, drag and drop is easier to use with Netbeans.