# How to get image file into Netbeans project tree?

Tags: netbeans, image-file

For my web application I am developing in netbeans I need access to an image file.

However, using an absolute file path to the location on my computer where the file is located doesn't work.

Hence I tried to include the file into my netbeans project in order to be able to refer to it with a relative file path.

Here:

[How do I add an image file in netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880877/how-do-i-add-an-image-file-in-netbeans)

it is claimed that one could simply copy and paste the file into the desired folder of one's Netbeans project tree (inside the IDE).

However, this doesn't work either.

How can I get this file file (it's a png file by the way) into my Netbeans Web App?

Comment: Which type of web application like PHP, Java EE or simple HTML?

Comment: it's Java Web Application in Netbeans